# Android view pager: how to distinguish user and programmatic swipes?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I use `ViewPager.setCurrentItem()` to automatically swipe to the next page every few seconds. I'd like to disable this as soon as the user starts swiping himself. As far as I can tell, `OnPageChangedListener` gets triggered in the same way whether the swipe came from the user or not. It seems like `beginFakeDrag()` could help, but it requires to drag by a specified number of pixels, which isn't practical.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you familiar with [SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)? It indicates that the pager is currently being dragged by the user.

**Example**

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {


    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) { 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            // User has dragged
        }
    }
});
```